# Orthogonality of summed wave functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hilbert-space

**Problem.** I know that the two wave functions $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ are all normalized and orthogonal. I now want to prove that this implies that $\Psi_3=\Psi_1+\Psi_2$ is orthogonal to $\Psi_4=\Psi_1-\Psi_2$.

**My naive solution.** From the premises, we know that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi_1^*\Psi_1 dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi_2^*\Psi_2 dx=1$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi_1^*\Psi_2 dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi_2^*\Psi_1 dx=0$$

We also have $(z_1+z_2)^*=z_1^*+z_2^*$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi_3^*\Psi_4 dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (\Psi_1+\Psi_2)^*(\Psi_1-\Psi_2)dx \\ 
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(\Psi_1^*+\Psi_2^*)(\Psi_1-\Psi_2)dx\\
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(\Psi_1^*\Psi_1-\Psi_1^*\Psi_2+\Psi_2^*\Psi_1-\Psi_2^*\Psi_2)dx\\
=1-0+0-1=0\,,$$

which is equivalent with what we wanted to prove. Is this a legitimate proof? Is there any simpler way to do this? I am afraid I still haven't grasped how wave functions behave mathematically, so I may have missed somethings very obvious here.

*Edit*: The solution manual somehow uses normalization factors for $\Psi_3$ and $\Psi_4$. How are these factors when you don't actually know the exact functions? And how does this relate to the concept of orthogonality?

Comment: Yes, you do need normalization factors so that $\int |\Psi_3|^2 dx = 1$, but your proof as it stands is correct. You directly calculated their inner product and found it to be zero, hence orthogonal vectors.

Comment: Braket notation might be simpler, but yours is good enough.

Comment: I don't understand why I would need $\int |\Psi_3|^2 dx=1$. And how would the bracket notation help?

Comment: You will probably get to Dirac/braket notation later in your course. But it would help by doing away with the integrals in this problem.

Comment: I have seen the braket notation a couple of times, and I figure that we here want to show that $\langle\Psi_4|\Psi_3\rangle=\langle\Psi_1-\Psi_2|\Psi_1+\Psi_2\rangle=0$, but I can't really see how I am supposed to go on without using the integral.

Comment: @PoetryInMotion: The underlying assumption is that the symbols "plus ($+$)" and "minus ($-$)" that you used to express $\Psi_3$ and $\Psi_4$ in terms of the "orthonormal basis" states $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ do in fact represent the corresponding arithmetic operations between the complex number values of inner products. Consequently: $\langle \Psi_1 - \Psi_2 |  \Psi_1 + \Psi_2 \rangle \text{=(means the same as)=} \langle \Psi_1 | \Psi_1 \rangle + \langle \Psi_1 | \Psi_2 \rangle - \langle \Psi_2 | \Psi_1 \rangle - \langle \Psi_2 | \Psi_2 \rangle$ which can be readily evaluated further (being $0$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem could be done more simply through the application of linear algebra. You want to prove that

$$\langle \psi_1 - \psi_2 | \psi_1 + \psi_2 \rangle = 0$$

The inner product is analogous to the dot product of linear algebra, and it is distributive. Distributing, we find that

$$\begin{aligned}
\langle \psi_1 - \psi_2 | \psi_1 + \psi_2 \rangle &= \langle \psi_1 - \psi_2 | \psi_1 \rangle + \langle \psi_1 - \psi_2 | \psi_2 \rangle \\
&= \langle \psi_1 | \psi_1 \rangle - \langle \psi_2 | \psi_1 \rangle + \langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle - \langle \psi_2 | \psi_2 \rangle
\end{aligned}
$$

Because $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are orthogonal and normalized, you know $\langle \psi_i | \psi_j \rangle = \delta_{i j}$. Substituting, the above expression evaluates to $1 - 0 + 0 - 1 = 0$, demonstrating that the two vectors are indeed orthogonal.

Your approach - using the integrals - was also valid, and fundamentally similar to mine here. However, by noting that the relation you used ($\langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! \psi_1^* \psi_2 \, \mathrm{d}x$)  satisfied the definition of an inner product, the integrals can be omitted.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! However, I still don't understand what the normalization factors have to do with the question. Both $\Psi_3$ and $\Psi_4$ happens have the normalization factor $1/\sqrt{2}$, but can't have anything to do with their orthogonality, can it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why you'd need the normalization factors here. It's clear that if $\langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle = 0$, then $\langle k \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle = k \langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle = 0$.

Comment: @PoetryInMotion Can you explain the context in which the solution manual used the normalization factors?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that I was supposed to both investigate the orthogonality of $\Psi_3$ and $\Psi_4$ **and** normalize $\Psi_3$ and $\Psi_4$. The explains why the solution manual disused normalization constants.

Comment: All right. Since you correctly found the normalization factor above, I take it you don't need help with that part.